# Image not responding to zoom on double tap

Tags: iphone, ios

My UIImage is not zooming with the following code.  The taps are recognized however the zoom does not work.  Its basically the taptozoom code from the iOS dev site with a navigation controller floating behind the UIScrollView and UIImageView.  This TapToZoom code works without the navigation controller.  Is there problem with the image stretching to allow the navigation bar at the top?

```
#import "Map.h"

#define ZOOM_VIEW_TAG 100
#define ZOOM_STEP 1.5


@interface Map (UtilityMethods)
- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center;
@end


@implementation Map

@synthesize imageScrollView, imageView;

- (void)loadView {
    //imageScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   // [self.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    //[self.imageView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
     NSLog(@"beginning of loadView in map.m");

    [super loadView];




    // set the tag for the image view
    [imageView setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];
    //imageScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    // add gesture recognizers to the image view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)];

    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [twoFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];        //added self to fix subview
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];

    [singleTap release];
    [doubleTap release];
    [twoFingerTap release];

    // calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
    [imageScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
    [imageScrollView setZoomScale:minimumScale];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.imageScrollView = nil;
    self.imageView = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [imageScrollView release];
    [imageView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate methods

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return [imageScrollView viewWithTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];
}

/************************************** NOTE **************************************/
/* The following delegate method works around a known bug in zoomToRect:animated: */
/* In the next release after 3.0 this workaround will no longer be necessary      */
/**********************************************************************************/
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scale+0.01 animated:NO];
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scale animated:NO];
}

#pragma mark TapDetectingImageViewDelegate methods

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // single tap does nothing for now
    NSLog(@"single tap detected");
}

- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // double tap zooms in
    NSLog(@"beginning handleDoubleTap to zoom");
    float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] * ZOOM_STEP;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
    [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

- (void)handleTwoFingerTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // two-finger tap zooms out
    float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] / ZOOM_STEP;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
    [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark UIScroll Subview




#pragma mark Utility methods

- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {

    CGRect zoomRect;
    NSLog(@"zoomRectForScale");

    // the zoom rect is in the content view's coordinates. 
    //    At a zoom scale of 1.0, it would be the size of the imageScrollView's bounds.
    //    As the zoom scale decreases, so more content is visible, the size of the rect grows.
    zoomRect.size.height = [imageScrollView frame].size.height / scale;
    zoomRect.size.width  = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / scale;

    // choose an origin so as to get the right center.
    zoomRect.origin.x    = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y    = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

    NSLog(@"end of zoom rect");
    return zoomRect;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

## import "RootViewController.h"

## define ZOOM_VIEW_TAG 100

## define ZOOM_STEP 1.5

@interface RootViewController (UtilityMethods)
- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center;
@end

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize imageScrollView, imageView, mySlider;

- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
  mySlider.value = [NSString stringWithFormat:imageScrollView.[sender value]];

  //mySlider.value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.1f", [sender value]];

  //myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.1f", [sender value]];
  }
- (void)loadView {
  [super loadView];

  // set the tag for the image view
  [imageView setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];

  // add gesture recognizers to the image view
  UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
  UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
  UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)];

  [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
  [twoFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

  [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
  [imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
  [imageView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];

  [singleTap release];
  [doubleTap release];
  [twoFingerTap release];

  // calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
  float minimumScale = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
  [imageScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
  [imageScrollView setZoomScale:minimumScale];
  }
- (void)viewDidUnload {
  self.imageScrollView = nil;
  self.imageView = nil;
  }
- (void)dealloc {
  [imageScrollView release];
  [imageView release];
  [super dealloc];
  }

## pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate methods

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  return [imageScrollView viewWithTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];
  }

/************************************** NOTE **************************************/
/* The following delegate method works around a known bug in zoomToRect:animated: */
/* In the next release after 3.0 this workaround will no longer be necessary      */
/******************************************************************************/
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scale+0.01 animated:NO];
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scale animated:NO];
}

## pragma mark TapDetectingImageViewDelegate methods

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
  // single tap does nothing for now
  }
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
  // double tap zooms in
  float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] * ZOOM_STEP;
  CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
  [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
  }
- (void)handleTwoFingerTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
  // two-finger tap zooms out
  float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] / ZOOM_STEP;
  CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
  [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
  }

## pragma mark Utility methods

- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {

  CGRect zoomRect;

  // the zoom rect is in the content view's coordinates. 
  //    At a zoom scale of 1.0, it would be the size of the imageScrollView's bounds.
  //    As the zoom scale decreases, so more content is visible, the size of the rect grows.
  zoomRect.size.height = [imageScrollView frame].size.height / scale;
  zoomRect.size.width  = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / scale;

  // choose an origin so as to get the right center.
  zoomRect.origin.x    = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
  zoomRect.origin.y    = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

  return zoomRect;
  }

@end

Comment: Please format your code properly. In addition, it'd be more helpful to the end user and other folks looking at the question if you can summarize what changes you made, so it's more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

ImageViews by default do not respond to user interaction by default, yo have to set it:

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar for trying.  I would have loved this to fix it, however it still doesn't zoom.

Comment: There is a navigation bar at the top and I'm wondering if that is interfering with it.

Comment: I'm also getting this error message from the debugger       2011-11-09 13:13:42.201 Robofair2011[353:707] Ignoring call to [UIPanGestureRecognizer setTranslation:inView:] since gesture recognizer is not active.

Comment: I'm also getting these values when I ask for the rectangles coordinates in the handleDoubleTap method:                                                              2011-11-09 14:12:50.177 Robofair2011[4977:207] handleDoubleTap zoomRect: {{-inf, -inf}, {inf, inf}}

Answer (score 0):

you need make sure the single tap recognizer waits for the double tap to fail.

```
[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-loadView` must be overridden ONLY to initialize `self.view` - nothing else. As I can't see a code initializing your `self.view` I presume your view comes out from a nib file, therefore you must NOT override the `-loadView` method or if the super class takes care of this initialization, you don't have to override it and call `[super loadView]`, but the code you have put there is totally in the wrong place. Move all your logic to `viewDidLoad` except the lines:

```
// calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
    [imageScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
    [imageScrollView setZoomScale:minimumScale];
```

These put in `viewWillAppear:`, because this is the place where the geometry of the view hierarchy is being already correctly set, and you can have accurate `frame` properties.