# UIImageView zoom, tap, gestures don't work

Tags: iphone, ios, image, scrollview

I am using Apple code for just zoom the `UIImageView` on taps and gestures. But its not work ?

Please see this Apple's link [apple code for image zooming by taps and gestures](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Listings/1_TapToZoom_Classes_RootViewController_m.html)

```
-(void)veiwDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];// Edited my self 

    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; // Edited my self

    //All code below same.... like Apple's code

    // set the tag for the image view
    [imageView setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];

    // add gesture recognizers to the image view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)];

    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [twoFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];

    [singleTap release];
    [doubleTap release];
    [twoFingerTap release];

    // calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
    [imageScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
    [imageScrollView setZoomScale:minimumScale];
}
```

Comment: what happens? any error message?

Comment: no errors... i see my image but tap and gestures not work on images

Comment: So you have created the tap functions and put logs or breakpoints in them and they never got hit?

Comment: @Dima yes. i not got any response on tap.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you set your imageView to be `userInteractionEnabled = YES;` .. its assign to `NO` by default.

Comment: i already do userInteractionEnabled = YES, and see similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044476/image-not-responding-to-zoom-on-double-tap

Comment: ok then .. show us the piece of code where you add the gesture to the imageView so we can provide some help.

Answer (score 2):

change the function name from

```
-(void) veiwDidLoad
```

to

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
```

I has a problem like that as well, does that fix it?